# Expected value of number of games

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The Canadiens meet the Bruins in a four-of-seven series. Although the Canadian is given a 75% chance of winning each game independently, the Bruins have just won the first two games of the series.

Let T be the number of games that will be played in the series. Find

1. the mass function of T and E [T]
2. the probability that the Canadian wins the series

Here, the series will be finished when one team wins 4 games first? So, I think T can obtain these values: 4, 5, 6, 7.

Pr (T=4) = 0.25 x 0.25 = 0.0625

Pr (T=5) = 3 x 0.25 x 0.25 x 0.75

But I'm not sure about this, someone pls help me.

Answer (score 1):

Your $Pr(T=5)$ is not correct because if there are $5$ games the Bruins must win the fifth.  There are therefore only $2$ orders of wins that we should count.  For $6$ games you need to consider the Canadiens winning all of the next four plus the Bruins winning one of the next three and the fourth.  $7$ games will be everything that is left.

Comment: For the second part, is this just count the number of possibilities that the C win, then divide by all the outcomes? I mean, is there any relation with the probability that C win each game?

Comment: Just like you did for four games, you have to consider the probability that each team wins the game in question and multiply by $\frac 14$ or $\frac 34$ as appropriate